# How to send a Ctrl-Z in Perl

Tags: perl, sms

I'm trying to send a Ctrl-Z command in a string, this is what I'm doing:

```
$command = "Prueba de código\26";
$port->write($command);
my $answer = $port->read(255);
```

Where "command" is the string that I want to send trough "port" (Device::SerialPort), and I'm trying to capture the response with "answer", the problem is that I'm think that the \26 (Ctrl-Z) is not working. The port is a cell phone connected and the objective is to send an SMS wich will say "Prueba de código" trough this phone. I need this Ctrl-Z to be sended because this is interpreted as the end of the text.

Answer (score 3):

The `\nnn` notation treats the numeric arguments as octal digits, so you are really sending `chr(22)` (Ctrl+V?)

```
$ perl -e 'print ord("\26")'
22
```

Character 26 can be expressed in all of these ways (and probably a few others)

```
chr(26)
"\032"
"\x1a"
"\cZ"
```